# Distributing Items equally in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Goal: Show a list (RecyclerView) of items horizontally in a way, that they are distributed equally on the screen and make the margin between them at least X dp, so that the View is scrollable, if not all Views fit on the screen.

I hope the following images will help you understand my question:

Here I got two items that are distributed equally over the screen's width:
[image: Few Items]

Here I got a lot of items; the "minimal margin" is used between the items and the Recycler is scrolling
[image: Lots of items]

I achieved this behaviour with measuring my View beforehand and then calculate the margin between the views manually, setting it within `onBindViewHolder`. This seems to be a dirty way of doing this, especially as I need to call `requestLayout` for each `itemView`.

I tried some things using `weights`, but that did not seem to work oput as expected. I am using a `LinearLayoutManager` for my `RecyclerView`.

Does anyone have any suggestion how this behaviour could be achieved in a better and cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **recyclerView.addItemDecoration** method to add your custom item decoration and solve your spacing problem. The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alexfu/f7b8278009f3119f523a). Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I could use it instead of margins, but still this seems to be a weird approach. Thank you though.